# package not found - ROS PCL Tutorial

Tags: ros, pcl, tutorial, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey, I am new to ROS and want to work with pointclouds. I did exactly the ROS PCL tutorial as written in http://wiki.ros.org/pcl/Tutorials

**CMakeLists in ~/catkin_ws/src/my_pcl_tutorial:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(my_pcl_tutorial)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  pcl_conversions
  pcl_ros
  roscpp
  sensor_msgs
)

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_executable(example src/example.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

**package.xml:**

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <package>
  <name>my_pcl_tutorial</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The my_pcl_tutorial package</description>

  <maintainer email="viki@todo.todo">viki</maintainer>

  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>pcl_conversions</build_depend>
  <build_depend>pcl_ros</build_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>sensor_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>libpcl-all-dev</build_depend>
  <run_depend>libpcl-all</run_depend>
  <run_depend>pcl_conversions</run_depend>
  <run_depend>pcl_ros</run_depend>
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>sensor_msgs</run_depend>
  <export>
  </export>
</package>
```

, but it does not seem to incorporate the package:

**rosrun error:**

```
rosrun my_pcl_tutorial example input:=/narrow_stereo_textured/points2
[rospack] Error: package 'my_pcl_tutorial' not found
```

Version: Indigo 1.11.8, but it does not work on jade either.
I did all the previous standard ROS tutorials, but dumpster beginner mistakes likely happened.
Any help is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244268/package-not-found---ros-pcl-tutorial/) by [anonymous28046](https://answers.ros.org/users/28046/anonymous28046/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2016-09-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, after a few minutes of doing nothing regarding ROS at all, it apparently finds the package now.
Sorry, but I have no idea why it is working after the delay.

Command line history:

```
784  catkin_make
  785  cd ~/catkin_ws/
  786  roscore
  787  source devel/setup.bash 
  788  roscore
  789  rosrun my_pcl_tutorial example input:=/narrow_stereo_textured/points2  ##did not work here##
  790  cd ~/catkin_ws/
  791  source devel/setup.bash 
  792  printenv | grep ROS
  793  cd devel
  794  ls -a
  795  cd include/
  796  ls -a
  797  cd ..
  798  cd src
  799  ls -a
  800  cd ..
  801  printenv | grep ROS
  802  rospack find my_pcl_tutorial 
  803  roscore
  804  cd ~/catkin_ws/
  805  rosrun my_pcl_tutorial example input:=/narrow_stereo_textured/points2 ##works
```

---

Originally posted by [anonymous28046](https://answers.ros.org/users/28046/anonymous28046/) with karma: 65 on 2016-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anonymous28046](https://answers.ros.org/users/28046/anonymous28046/) on 2016-10-11**:
This is the solution, I just can not accept it as I do not have enough points.